# Hexo does not generate /tags/ page

Tags: hexo

I added tags to articles like this:

```
tags: [tag1]
```

And its page /tags/tag1 was generated correctly. But when I tried to open /tags, not existing, just got the below:

```
Cannot GET /tags/
```

I want to navigate tags. What configuration was I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Hexo "tags" page by running the following command:

```
hexo new page "tags"
```

Once this is run, you should be able to see a "tags" folder under "source" and everything should work fine. (e.g. http://localhost:4000/tags/ )

[image: Hexo tags folder]